Is Wild Shape affected by Moonbeam?
Under the 2014 rules, it was generally accepted that a Druid in Wild Shape was not affected by Moonbeam because they were not shapechangers.
Now, it seems this is different under the 2024 rules:
Moonbeam states:

When the Cylinder appears, each creature in it makes a Constitution
saving throw. On a failed save, a creature takes 2d10 Radiant damage,
and if the creature is shape-shifted (as a result of the Polymorph
spell, for example), it reverts to its true form and can’t shape-shift
until it leaves the Cylinder.

And Shape-Shifting, as defined in the Glossary:

If an effect, such as Wild Shape or the Polymorph spell, lets you
shape-shift, its description specifies what happens to you. Unless
that description says otherwise, any ongoing effects on
you—conditions, spells, curses, and the like—carry over from one form
to the other. You revert to your true form if you die.

Is Wild Shape affected now by Moonbeam, or am I missing something?

Moonbeam affects Wild Shape
As you've cited, Wild Shape is explicitly considered shape-shifting under the new definition, and therefore falls under the relevant clause in Moonbeam:

if the creature is shape-shifted

